# Not a valid Office Add In

Tags: ms-office, vsto, add-in, excel-2007

I developed a new Office 2007 addin using VS 2008 and VSTO. after this I go to 
Office->Excel Options->AddIns->COM AddIns and GO... If I select the .dll which I ve created I get the error

```
'<path>' is not a valid Office Add In.
```

If I run it using the Visual Studio 2008 at my development machine, it works fine and I see the add-in.

I searched so many posts but didn't get a solution.

Answer (score 10):

Excel kept rejecting the Add-In, so the solution for me was doing it directly via the registry.

Save the below text as a .reg file, replace the Manifest path and FriendlyName to suit your PROJECT and double click the reg file to add the key to the Registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins\PROJECTExcelAddIn]
"Manifest"="file:///C:\\TFS\\Pg.PROJECT\\PROJECTExcelAddIn\\Src\\PROJECTExcelAddIn\\PROJECTExcelAddIn\\bin\\Debug\\PROJECTExcelAddIn.vsto"
"FriendlyName"="PROJECTExcelAddIn"
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
"Description"="PROJECTExcelAddIn - Excel add-in for PROJECT."
```

Answer (score 4):

VSTO does not create COM Addins. You will need to install your add-in on non-development machines. The article *Adding the Office Primary Interop Assemblies as a Prerequisite in your ClickOnce installer* at http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/archive/2008/05/08/adding-the-office-primary-interop-assemblies-as-a-prerequisite-in-your-clickonce-installer-mary-lee.aspx will get you started.

Comment: This actually isn't true.  VSTO does create COM AddIns.  You will find the Add-Ins you create in VSTO residing in the COM Add-Ins in Microsoft Office.

Comment: @Justin  Yes, but that is a wrapper in the VSTO run-time library created to call your CLR code. If you want your .NET Class to support COM, that is a whole other process. Do you have any references?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you'll have to publish the addin. Then, the Visual Studio will create a folder in *Debug* folder named *app.publish* folder with other folders in and, the important thing, a setup file named *setup.exe*.

Comment: After spending half a day of searching, this worked. it gave me the option for where to place the `publish\` folder. in my case I am running windows 10 on Parallels through my Mac.