# Deploying Excel Addin in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, excel-addins

I have successfully coded a little application level add-in for Excel in C# in Visual Studio. But I seem to struggle with the deployment.

I have tried the ClickOnce and Windows Installer variants and they work fine, but not the way I wanted: I would like to be able to install my Add-in though the "Developer" Tab in Excel by pressing "COM Add-Ins" and then "add..."
But Excel says:

> It doesn't recognize neither the .dll nor the .vsto nor the setup.exe files as a valid Addin.

Screenshots for reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJOqK.jpg

How can I compile my code that Excel recognizes it?
It seems like I'm missing a step here and I couldn't find any solutions for this online, so I thought I could ask you for help.

Comment: Have you checked if the bitness of Excel.exe and your COM-Addin is the same?

Comment: Possible related: [Not a valid Office Add In](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1387983/4519059) ;).